# Getting ValueError trying to plot a graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have an Arduino sketch that is putting time, temperature values into a `loggedData.dat` file. Just looking at the file using the Arduino serial monitor it looks fine. But when I try to plot a graph with it using the python script below I get an error:

```
File "loggedData.py", line 44, in <module>
x.append(Float(p[0])) ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

If I simply create a file named `loggedData.dat` by manually typing in values that looks exactly like the original file, such as:

```
1.00, 71.3

2.00, 71.6

3.00, 71.7

4.00, 71.8
```

It works fine, I get a good graph. Apparently there is something getting into the `loggedData.dat` file that I cannot see using the serial monitor. Any suggestions?

```
import sys, serial, time
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
serPort   = '/dev/ttyS1'
dataFile  = open( "./loggedData.dat", "w" );

print "\nAttempting to open Serial Port : ", serPort, "for logging\n"

ser       = serial.Serial( serPort, 9600 )
if ( ser.isOpen() == False ):
    print "ERROR: Unable to open serial port ", serPort, "\n"
    exit(0);
else:
    print "Port ", serPort, " opened\n"

sys.stdout.flush()
print "Hit return to start logging ..."
key = sys.stdin.readline()
ser.write('1');
print "Logging started. CTRL-C to stop\n"
while True:
    try:
        line = ser.readline()
        print line;
        dataFile.write( line )

    except KeyboardInterrupt:                    # CTRL-C triggered here
        ser.write( '0' )
        print "Logging Stopped\n"
        break;

ser.flush()
ser.close()
dataFile.close()
print "Port ", serPort, " closed\n"
print "\nPlot graph (y/n) ?"
key = sys.stdin.read(1)

if key == 'y':
    print "\nPlotting graph ...\n"
    f     = open( "loggedData.dat", 'r' )
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    x = []
    y = []
    for line in lines:
        p = line.split( ',' )
        x.append( float( p[0] ) )
        y.append( float( p[1] ) )

    fig   = plt.figure()
    graph = fig.add_subplot(111)
    graph.set_title( "Data logged from Arduino UNO" )
    graph.plot( x, y, 'ro' )
    plt.show()

    print "Plot complete\n"
else:
    print "Finishing\n"

time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: try to check that you open the same file in the same dir ( your write-access directs to "./loggedData.dat", while read-access "loggedData.dat" which need not be the same file. Have you inspected the serial-data in HEX? Both control-characters and international decimal number format { point | comma } matter.

Comment: I removed the ./ from the first loggedData.dat but it didn't help. Not sure if this is the right way to do it but I added a Serial.print(t,HEX); and Serial.print(celsius,HEX); to the Arduino sketch. The serial monitor showed the same numbers but extended many more places past the decimal point. I don't see any problems.

Comment: Great, Rico, sould you then post the byte-exact copy of the terminal output of your serial-data stream, as being received and the same from the log-file? Some 50 samples each? There are smart numpy file-input functions, to get diirectly plot-able array-objects, so worth debug the serial-input/log-file side.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I don't know how to get the byte-exact copy?

Answer (score 0):

if ctrl characters are stuck to your variable - you could try

```
x.append(Float(p[0].strip()))
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried adding .strip() but I still get same error.